# Steering wheel vibrations 2011 VW Touareg 3.6L V6 Petrol

Tags: vw, steering, vibration

I have a 2011 VW Touareg 3.6L V6 petrol that has done 55,000km on the clock. At speeds above 120km/h, I start to experience a lot of steering wheel vibrations. I have checked my wheel alignment and wheel balancing and all seems to be okay. What could be the cause? No vibrations are felt at speeds below 120km/h.

Comment: The number of times I've had someone come to me and say "the wheel balance is ok" and when I put them on my balancer they're a mile out..